# What's the compiler used by Xcode for Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gcc

What's the compiler used by Xcode for Objective-c, it is GCC?

Comment: Use LLVM wherever possible;  which pretty much means everywhere these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is by default Apple's LLVM in newer versions of Xcode (3.1 and later); it previously used gcc (which is still installed by Xcode, and which can be specified as the compiler to use).

Comment: Note that you can still use GCC on the actual Xcode version, by editing your target's build settings.

Answer (score 2):

GCC and LLVM can be used.

From [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#llvm-compiler):

> **Apple LLVM Compiler 2.0**
>
> Apple LLVM is the next-generation compiler
>   technology powering Xcode 4. Based on the vibrant open source LLVM.org
>   project led by Apple engineers, the Apple LLVM compiler is modern
>   thinking, tuned for iPhone, iPad, and the multi-core Mac. Apple LLVM
>   is fast. It compiles code twice as quickly as GCC, yet produces
>   applications that also run faster. The compiler was built from the
>   ground up as a set of highly optimized libraries, easy to extend, easy
>   to optimize, and designed for today’s modern chip architectures. In
>   Xcode 4, the full Apple LLVM compiler stack — from the front end
>   parser, to the back end code optimizer — has great support for C,
>   Objective-C, and C++. Syntax highlighting, code completion, and every
>   other index-driven feature is handled by the LLVM parser. If the
>   compiler knows about a symbol, so does the Xcode IDE. C, C++, and
>   Objective-C are all accurately understood at editing time, exactly as
>   they are when building.*